# VueJS: Filter through objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm working on a vue-js problem.

I got an `data`-element (object) called `items`. I am looping through these products and display a dropdown with a list of the items.

Now I would like to show **only** those items who have a value in an array thats called "Watt" and a `Title`.

This is an example item of `items`:

```
Item

-Title

-Date

-Specifications [Array]

-- [0] Name: "Watt"

-- [0] Value: 5

-- [1] Name: "Weight"

-- [1] Value: 100
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not VueJS specific. In Javascript you filter an array with Array#filter. Example:

```
items = items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Title && item.Specifications.some(function(specification) {
         return specification.Name === "Watt";
    });    
});
```

To understand this have a look at [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) functions. The above code basically filters the items array by the condition that the item has at least one (some) element in the Specification array where the `Name` is "Watt" and has a title.